# NuSOAP 0.7.2 sending empty SOAP requests

Tags: php, xml, api, nusoap, soap-client

OK, so before I get flooded with answers like "Use PHP's built-in SOAP extension" or "upgrade to nuSOAP 0.9.5" I just want to make it clear that these are not an option in my situation. I'm working in a hosted environment and I'm lucky they even had this legacy version of nuSOAP installed on the server.

That said, I need some help with my SOAP requests.

Here's what I have so far:

```
require_once('nusoap_0.7.2/nusoap.php');
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
$wsdl = "https://api.bronto.com/v4?wsdl";
$ns = "https://api.bronto.com/v4";

$client = new soapclient($wsdl, array('trace'=>1, 'encoding'=>'UTF-8'));

// Login
$token = "API-TOKEN";
$sessionId = $client->call('login', array('apiToken' => $token), $ns, $ns);
if (!$sessionId) {
  print "Login failed.\n";
  exit;
}
print_r($sessionId);

$client->setHeaders(array($ns, 'sessionHeader', array('sessionId' => $sessionId)));

echo htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES); // debug request
```

This is what the login call to the API returns:

```
Array ( [faultcode] => soap:Client [faultstring] => 107: There was an error in your soap request. Please examine the request and try again. [detail] => There was an error in your soap request. Please examine the request and try again. )
```

This is what the SOAP request ends up looking like:

```
POST /v4 HTTP/1.0 Host: api.bronto.com User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.7.2 (1.94) 
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8 
SOAPAction: "" 
Content-Length: 379 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns7166="https://api.bronto.com/v4">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
   <parameters/>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The SOAP request appears to be sending fine but the envelope is empty. I suspect I may need to replace the arrays in the request with SoapVal objects, but the documentation on this object is difficult to get my head around.

For reference, this is the PHP SOAP code I am trying to translate to nusoap 0.7.2

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

$wsdl = "https://api.bronto.com/v4?wsdl";
$url = "https://api.bronto.com/v4";

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1, 'encoding' => 'UTF-8'));
$client->__setLocation($url);

// Login
$token = "ADD YOUR API TOKEN HERE";
$sessionId = $client->login(array("apiToken" => $token))->return;
if (!$sessionId) {
    print "Login failed.\n";
    exit;
}
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array(new SoapHeader("http://api.bronto.com/v4", 'sessionHeader', array('sessionId' => $sessionId))));
print "Login was successful.\n";
```

Comment: the same situation by me. did you found any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I had had same problem even on NuSOAP/0.9.11 and later. ;-) `SOAPAction: ""`

NuSOAP has several issues. E.g. it supports only wsdl-mode for me, and your NuSOAP api usage is wrong (new nusoap_client second parameter).

For using wsdl-mode you must smth like this:

```php
$wsdlurl = 'https://api-sandbox.direct.yandex.com/v5/campaigns?wsdl'; // your wsdl url
$token = '<your token if needed>';
$locale = 'en';

// Construct NuSOAP-client
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdlurl, 'wsdl'); // second parameter must be boolean true or 'wsdl'

# Auth of NuSOAP-client
$client->authtype = 'basic'; /// but Yandex Direct needs 'bearer'
$client->decode_utf8 = 0;
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';

// ..... $client->setCredentials and $client->setHeaders if needed

// Call soap/wsdl api method
$result = $client->call(
  'get', 
  array('SelectionCriteria' => (object) array(), 'FieldNames' => array('Id', 'Name'))
); // string $operation (required), mixed $params (required), string $namespace (optional method namespace for non-WSDL), string $soapAction (optional SOAPAction value for non-WSDL)

// Output
echo "Request:<pre>".htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES)."</pre>";
echo "Response:<p>".nl2br(htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES))."</p>";

// Debug
echo '<hr><pre>'.htmlspecialchars($client->debug_str, ENT_QUOTES).'</pre>';
```

P.S.: If you need Yandex, [fixed lib is here](https://github.com/proxy-m/nusoap) and samples [client4yandex](https://github.com/proxy-m/nusoap/blob/master/samples/client4yandex.php).

[image]